# Firebase Exact Same versions Error?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

I get the error below

> All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 17.3.0, 17.0.0, 16.0.1, 16.0.0, 15.0.1.

my Firebase Messaging Dependency Is:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
```

and Class Path is:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

How To Resolve this?

Comment: The reference to `gms` actually covers all Play Services libraries. You probably have more of those in your gradlefile than just the ones in the snippet you shared. Please update your question to include the [minimal *complete* build file with which you can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

As I said [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52644464/6444297) this problem will be solved if you use these versions:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
```