# Firebase, com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0 Not Working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found a lot of postings that talk about this.
I'm 2 days trying to insert firebase implementation but without success.
I'm going crazy because I can not understand what he does not like about my code.
can anyone help me?

[image: build.gradle Project]

[image: build.gradle Module]

As you can see com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0 it is not read in any way and reports an error.
I tried to use different versions but the result does not change

I read that it could be some non-activated TOOLS SDKs but apparently, it does not affect ...

[image: my SDK tools]

I do not know how to get out of it

if someone were to have a good idea, it's welcome! :)

Comment: The problem is the last line of your app `build.gradle` file. You have com.android.application instead of `apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: You can read the step here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk

Comment: Hello @MatPag Thanks so much for your reply! I inserted apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the end of my code and synced but com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.3 is still with an error, highlighted in red. .

Comment: @SkleroMc If you are using `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` what is the error? Please responde with @.

Comment: Please include your code and possible errors as text instead of images.

Comment: @SkleroMc Check my answer, please. It may solve your problem. if it works check it as true answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line on your app `build.gradle`. Also you will need to add the `google-services.json` file generated when you create your Firebase project.

Reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 4):

Using these versions will solve your problem. don't forget to sync project with gradle files:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
```

Answer (score -1):

try to change each and every version to 11.8.0 like

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'

for auth ,database ,storage,messaging,related to firebase

Answer (score -2):

Firebase version must be the same

```
Implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.3'
Implementation 'com.google.firebase-core:16.0.3'
```

or

Instead of **Implementation** use **Compile**

Comment: This is no longer true.  Since version 15, the Android client SDKs version independently from each other.

Comment: Hello @DoctorDroid Haiti,  Thanks so much for your reply!  I replaced the two implementations inside the dependencies but it returns me the error 33