# Firebase cloud messaging gradle settings

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add firebase cloud messaging in my app but the problem happens to be in my gradle dependencies

this is what i'm adding in my dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
```

but it doesn't work ends up showing errors.

**My Project gradle :**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My App gradle :**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.package"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 12
        versionName "12.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:AndroidSpinKit:v1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Error Logcat**

[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lr5p.png)
Any solution ?? I also tried updating all dependencies to their new version but it also didn't worked.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Attach any logcat or ide error logs or screenshot.

Comment: Error like - Affected Modules: app

Comment: use the latest gradle --.>  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'` This page might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065209/firebase-com-google-firebasefirebase-messaging17-3-0-not-working

Comment: It is impossible to answer without the error you are getting.

Comment: Updated with logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by changing gradle version it worked me before, I too faced same issue few days back

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Firebase Android Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) for the latests versions available for the different cores of *Firebase* functionalities.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
```

Try updating it to the latest version available.

Comment: try to downgrade : play-services-stats :15.0.0 . since you are using 15.0.1 which is not an available version. @user2294087